# Textarea content/value not updating after set with jQuery then manually edited

Tags: jquery, forms

I've built an email form that is designed to allow a user to email a link to the current page to a friend, from themselves. The form simply contains the fields:

Your Name
Your Email Address
Friend's Name
Friend's Email Address
Message

The message is set to populate onchange of the "Your Name" input through jQuery including the contents of the "Your Name" field plus a short text string. From there, I want the user to then be able to edit the contents afterwards and for the resulting email to include the initially populated message, plus whatever the user adds. For some reason though, when the form is submitted, only the initial contents populated by jQuery comes through in the email despite the textarea including that plus what the user has added by typing into it. Here is the code that I'm using to initial populate the contents of the textarea. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$('.email-panel #input_1').on('change',(function(){
    var myname = $(this).val();
    var txt = $.trim(myname+' has sent you a delicious recipe! Clearly they have great taste.');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('textarea').val(txt);
}));
```

Comment: Make sure you have given name to your text area so it can be posted by Form to the server. If it is fine then please post the Form Html as well as the server side code which you have added to process form values and send email.

Comment: Hi K D, I've determined that it is very likely a conflict with Gravity Forms, a WordPress plugin that I've used to build the actual form. I think my best bet is to take it up with their support team as the code within the plugin is relatively complex. Thanks anyhow for your consideration.